# Why do we observe opposite motion of trees (nearer) and trees (distant) when seen from a moving frame?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, distance

If you are in a moving train or in a bus, what you observe is that the trees which are nearer to you move opposite to the direction of your motion. But the trees which are very far away from you, appear to be moving along with the direction of motion. Why it happens?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116425/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114748/2451

Comment: I have to answer briefly in a comment since this answer would not fit
the other question. It may be that your vehicle is slowly turning
toward the tree side, so that the far away tree is actually further
away on your path, i.e. projects orthogonally on your direction
further away. Trees that are close by are not affected. And this is
not an optical illusion.

Answer (score 1):

It's an optical illusion.  The trees at all distances will move in a direction opposite your motion, but the nearer trees will appear to move faster than the ones farther away.  If your eyes get used to the speed of the nearer trees, it may look like the farther ones are moving in the opposite direction.