# Why distant are stationary?

Tags: relative-motion

Why do for an observer looking out of the window through a fast moving train ,the distant objects appear to be stationary?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116425/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130999/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114748/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

If the speed of the train is not very high, the angular displacement of the distant object is too small to be observed.